# Join under FROM rather than under SELECT

Tags: sql-server

I am trying to join several tables together:

1. Dates Table/Column:

```
DECLARE @MinDate DATE = '20210416',
@MaxDate DATE = '20210419';

SELECT TOP (datediff(day, @MinDate, @MaxDate) + 1) dates = dateadd(day, row_number() OVER( ORDER BY a.object_id) - 1, @MinDate)
FROM       sys.all_objects a
CROSS JOIN sys.all_objects b

Output:
**----------**

dates
2021-04-16
2021-04-17
2021-04-18
2021-04-19
```

2. Bank Account Table

```
SELECT bankacc_number,
       bankacc_name,
       bankacc_currency
FROM   BankAccountsTable

Output:
**----------**

bankacc_number  bankacc_name  bankacc_currency
123456          BankAccount1  USD
789123          BankAccount2  EUR
```

I get the desired preliminary output by:

```
DECLARE @MinDate DATE = '20210416',
@MaxDate DATE = '20210419';

SELECT dat.dates,
       a.bankacc_number,
       a.bankacc_name,
       a.bankacc_currency

FROM
(SELECT TOP (datediff(day, @MinDate, @MaxDate) + 1) dates = dateadd(day, row_number() OVER( ORDER BY a.object_id) - 1, @MinDate)
FROM       sys.all_objects a
CROSS JOIN sys.all_objects b) as dat,
BankAccountsTable as a

Output:
**----------**

dates       bankacc_number  bankacc_name  bankacc_currency
2021-04-16  123456          BankAccount1  USD
2021-04-16  789123          BankAccount2  EUR
2021-04-17  123456          BankAccount1  USD
2021-04-17  789123          BankAccount2  EUR
2021-04-18  123456          BankAccount1  USD
2021-04-18  789123          BankAccount2  EUR
2021-04-19  123456          BankAccount1  USD
2021-04-19  789123          BankAccount2  EUR
```

I am able to create select subquery to retrieve Bank Balances but would prefer to somehow join this to the two tables in FROM instead of putting the below as a column:

```
DECLARE @MinDate DATE = '20210416',
@MaxDate DATE = '20210419';

SELECT dat.dates,
       a.bankacc_number,
       a.bankacc_name,
       a.bankacc_currency, 
(
              SELECT TOP 1 bankbalance.Balance
              FROM   bankflow
                     LEFT JOIN bankbalance
                     ON bankflow.id = bankbalance.id
              WHERE  bankflow.bankacc_number = a.bankacc_number
              AND    bankflow.date = dat.dates
              ORDER BY bankflow.date desc, bankflow.sequn_no desc) AS BankBalance
FROM
         (SELECT TOP (datediff(day, @MinDate, @MaxDate) + 1) dates = dateadd(day, 
          row_number() OVER( ORDER BY a.object_id) - 1, @MinDate)
         FROM       sys.all_objects a
         CROSS JOIN sys.all_objects b) as dat,
         BankAccountsTable as a
```

Is it possible to the above using joins within FROM rather than the above under SELECT?
I need to reference dates from the dates table and the accounts from the bank accounts table and I am unable to figure out how join everything together.

Comment: Probably `APPLY` will help, can you [edit]t and add the full query

Comment: @Charlieface added full query -

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**The `APPLY` operator works to create a new resultset per each row.** You can add as many columns as you need, they are accessible to all later joins and `WHERE` filters.

`CROSS APPLY` is like an inner join, `OUTER APPLY` is like a left join.

> **Note:** you should use proper join syntax, I have added `CROSS JOIN` for you.
> Also you should use aliases, they make the query more readable

```sql
DECLARE @MinDate DATE = '20210416',
@MaxDate DATE = '20210419';

SELECT dat.dates,
       a.bankacc_number,
       a.bankacc_name,
       a.bankacc_currency, 
       BankBalance.Balance
FROM
     (SELECT TOP (datediff(day, @MinDate, @MaxDate) + 1) dates = dateadd(day, 
          row_number() OVER( ORDER BY (SELECT 1)) - 1, @MinDate)
         FROM       sys.all_objects a
         CROSS JOIN sys.all_objects b
     ) as dat
CROSS JOIN BankAccountsTable as a
OUTER APPLY (
              SELECT TOP 1 bb.Balance
              FROM   bankflow bf
                     LEFT JOIN bankbalance bb
                     ON bf.id = bb.id
              WHERE  bf.bankacc_number = a.bankacc_number
              AND    bf.date = dat.dates
              ORDER BY bf.date desc, bf.sequn_no desc
) AS BankBalance
```